# Changing tab from external form

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl in Form A. I am trying to change that tab from Form B through a button.

I am using this code:

```
Dashboard.TabSystem.SelectedTab = tab_Dashboard
```

And Visual Studio is giving me the following error:

```
'tab_Dashboard' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

Maybe I am being stupid but I can't get it to see the tab page?

Comment: @Warcupine VB.NET - sorry for typo

Comment: Form B must "know" Form A for this to work. You can use Form A controls from Form B only if Form B has Form A's reference, and if what you're trying to access isn't restricted (you can code properties or getters for this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not declared then it's not a designer field. Is that just the name of the tab? Try getting the tab object from the `Dashboard.TabSystem`:

```
Dim tab As TabPage = Dashboard.TabSystem.TabPages("tab_Dashboard")
```

And then set the selected tab:

```
Dashboard.TabSystem.SelectedTab = tab
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, works apart from it's 'Dashboard.TabSystem.TabPages' instead of 'Dashboard.TabSystem.Tabs'